# Is it wrong to say "I am seeing a film"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, 
[This site](http://thefreedictionary.com/see) says "*I watched that film*" is the same as "*I saw that film*"

> 4. entertainment and sport Both see and watch are used when you are talking about entertainment or sport.
>
> When you go to the theatre or cinema, you say that you see a play or
>   film.
>
> *I saw that movie when I was a child.*
>
> *We saw him in 'Hamlet'.*
>
> Don't say that someone 'looks at' a play or film. Don't say, for
>   example 'I looked at that movie'.
>
> You say that someone watches television. You can say that someone
>   watches or sees a particular programme.
>
> *He spends hours watching television.*
>
> *He watched a rugby match on television.*
>
> *I saw his speech on the news.*
>
> Similarly, you say that someone watches a sport such as football, but
>   you can say that they watch or see a particular match.
>
> *More people are watching cricket than ever before.*
>
> *Did you watch the game last night?*
>
> *Millions of people saw the World Cup Final.*

However, in the dictionary, **see** in this meaning ***is not usually used in the progressive tenses***

> [See](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/see_1?q=see): [transitive] (not usually used in the progressive tenses) see
>   something to watch a game, television programme, performance, etc.
>
> *Did you see that programme on Brazil last night?*
>
> *In the evening we went to see a movie.*
>
> *Fifty thousand people saw the match.*

So, it is ok to say: **I am watching a film**

but is it ok to say: "**I am seeing a film**"?

Comment: The site doesn't suggest *watch* and *see* are the same in that context, irrespective of the progressive case.

Answer (score 5):

As  a native speaker, I would understand *I am seeing a film* to mean the speaker intends to go to a theater to watch a film in the future.

> I'm going into the city tomorrow.
>   --What are you doing there?
>   I'm seeing a documentary about global warming.

"I am watching a film" would mean that the speaker is currently engaged in the act.

> Phone rings.
>   Hello?
>   --Hi, it's me, Tom. Do you want to shoot some hoops?
>   No, I'm watching a film at the moment. How about tomorrow?

P.S. **Seeing a movie** refers to the occasion of going to a theater (or some other venue) in order to watch a film:

> We're seeing a movie at the new Ritz theater on Friday night.

or to the attendant physical circumstances or mode of the screening/viewing:

> Seeing a movie in IMAX is a very different experience from seeing it
>   on an iPad.

**Watching a movie** refers to what the audience  is doing as they become immersed in the film and the story it tells.

You can be interrupted while watching a movie. You cannot be interrupted while seeing a movie.

Comment: This effectively would mean that *"I am seeing a film"* and *"I will be seeing a film"* are identical!

Comment: @CinCout: That's right, both refer to a future event.  *She is arriving tomorrow* and *She will be arriving tomorrow* and *She is going to arrive tomorrow* and *She is to arrive tomorrow* are synonymous.

Comment: When you add words that specifically mean *"in the future"*, for instance *tomorrow* in the example you gave, this makes sense. But with the absence of such words, I doubt if that's the case.

Comment: @CinCout. Are you a native speaker?

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: @CinCout: If you are not a native speaker, I'm wondering what linguistic experience makes you think you know more than a native speaker in this instance.

Comment: Your answer sounds right to me (better than mine anyway), but usage of "I am seeing a film" must be pretty rare these days. I feel like most native speakers might get it, but I've never heard anyone actually use that phrase.

Comment: That's what I want to know. Is it something that only the native speakers will get because of their experience, or does it follow some grammar rules?

Comment: *(to be) seeing a film* is not at all uncommon. As I say in my answer, it is a way of expressing an intention to go to the movies. "We're going out to dinner and then seeing a movie afterwards" is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo OK, now I'm confused. In your example in your comment, if you  remove "then" and "afterward," the phrase doesn't connote future anymore. In fact, if you added "then" or "afterward" to ANY verb, that WOULD connote future. Right?

Comment: If you just said ***We're going out to dinner and seeing a movie***, the future connotation is purely implied by context -- unless you're eating in the theater. If someone asks, "What are you doing?" and you respond ***I'm seeing a movie***, that could mean you're currently at the theater watching a movie OR intend to watch one soon.

Comment: I could be way off, but I think what we might have here is a partially implemented idiom, if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatically OK to say ***I am seeing a film***, but it does sound awkward to me. It's probably better to say ***I am watching a film***. I think it has something to do with the fact that ***watching*** is often a single, ongoing event. You can watch something for 30 minutes or 2 hours or even 2 days.

***See*** has multiple meanings, but often refers to an event that is a single point in time, not ongoing. It might only take a fraction of a second to ***see something***. And so ***seeing*** can refer to many specific points in time instead of one ongoing event. For example, ***seeing someone*** means you are dating someone and that you see this person on multiple dates on different occasions. ***Watching someone*** means you are continuously looking at a person, perhaps while he/she dances naked in his/her bedroom, and you are wishing you were seeing that person instead of watching that person.

Comment: So, if someone is completing the movie over several sittings, *seeing* is still valid?

Comment: The answer implies that *I'm watching a film* and *I'm seeing a film* are interchangeable, which I don't think is the case.

Comment: @CinCout I've never actually heard anyone say "I am seeing a movie." But no, I don't think anyone would think seeing a movie would require several tubs of popcorn. Context is important here.

Comment: @userr2684291 Interesting observation. I see ***I watched a film*** and ***I saw a film*** as nearly identical in meaning. "Saw" maybe connotes a more casual manner of watching, but not necessarily. I have never heard ***I am seeing a film***, but I would assume it meant that I was having a deep understanding of a movie, like when I saw "Wild Hogs."